# cannot convert ‘const timeval’ to ‘__time_t {aka long int}’

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, time, c++

I'm trying to compile https://sourceforge.net/p/dom-s-orm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/

And whenever I try to compile it I get this error:

```
[root@localhost dev]# gmake all
(cd objects; gmake)
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/burst/dev/objects'
--> Compiling object helper Account from ../output/objects/Account_.cxx
In file included from ../output/objects/Account_.hxx:11:0,
                 from ../output/objects/Account_.cxx:4:
../build/contrib/DORM/include/Timestamp.hpp: In constructor ‘DORM::Timestamp::Timestamp(const timeval&)’:
../build/contrib/DORM/include/Timestamp.hpp:19:44: error: cannot convert ‘const timeval’ to ‘__time_t {aka long int}’ in initialization
    Timestamp(const struct timeval &t): tv{t} {};
                                            ^
gmake[1]: *** [../build/gmake/objects.gmk:59: ../output/objects/Account_.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/burst/dev/objects'
gmake: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2
```

The content of Timestamp.hpp is:

```
#ifndef DORM__INCLUDE__TIMESTAMP_HPP
#define DORM__INCLUDE__TIMESTAMP_HPP

#include <cppconn/sqlstring.h>

#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>


namespace DORM {

    class Timestamp {
        public:
            struct timeval tv;

            Timestamp(): tv{0, 0} {};
            Timestamp(const time_t &t): tv{t, 0} {};
            Timestamp(const struct timeval &t): tv{t} {};

            Timestamp(const std::string time_str);
            Timestamp(sql::SQLString time_str);

            operator time_t() { return tv.tv_sec; };
            operator timeval() { return tv; };
    };

}

#endif
```

Any help is welcomed to be able to fix this.

Thanks a lot!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since `struct timeval` is a simple C struct, it doesn't have a copy constructor. That makes `tv{t}` in

```
Timestamp(const struct timeval &t): tv{t} {};
```

an aggregate [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (see syntax 2), trying to initialize `tv.sec` with `t`. `tv.sec` is a `time_t` not a `struct timeval`, hence the error.

Use parentheses instead like so:

```
Timestamp(const struct timeval &t): tv(t) {};
```